# How can I get the base64 string of an image using JS

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm trying to get the base64 string of an image using only javascript.

This has to work only on firefox 3.5+ since it's a greasemonkey script.

I can't use the **canvas** workaround since it's on a another server and this throws a security exception.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there's a more elegant solution but you can create a canvas with the dimensions of your image, use drawImage to put your image on the canvas, use toDataURL with the MIME type that you want and get a data: URL which will be something like "data:image/png;base64," and then the base64 representation of the image in a given format.

Oh, I've just read that it's on another server. Then you can't have the base64. Sorry. The only information you can get are the dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

[base64.js](http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=210) is what you are looking for